# On the getallheaders() function problem in PHP on Apache servers

Tags: php, apache

In the PHP function getallheaders () unique to the Apache server, all request headers are retrieved and an array is returned, with all key initials in uppercase.

[image]

But in some images, I saw that specific parameters do not capitalize the first letter.

[image]

Do you need to set certain configurations to achieve this effect without changing the program code, or do you need to make some settings to the program code

Comment: Does this behavior make any problem to usage of code ? Can you just simply use strtolower function to fix any possible problem ?

Comment: headers are not intended to be case-sensitive. It shouldn't matter. Is this giving you an actual real-world problem?

Answer (score 0):

RFC2616 -- HTTP/1.1 defines header fields as case-insensitive.

You should convert array keys of `getallheaders()` to lower- or uppercase first.
You might want to take a look at `array_change_key_case()`;

Look at:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.2
- https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-change-key-case.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php